# Getting NoneType error on form submit with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, semantic-ui

I have a problem when I submit a form through pressing ENTER.

This is how my js code looks like:

```
  $.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'password_reset': '/account/password_reset/'
  }

  $('.ui.form')
    .form({
      fields: {
        email:  'empty'
      }
    })
    .api({
      action: 'password_reset',
      method: 'post',
      serializeForm: true,
      onSuccess: function () {
        $('.page.dimmer').dimmer('show');
        console.log('success')
      }
    })
  ;
```

If i press the submit button, everything works alright, but if I submit the form pressing ENTER, in console I get:

```
[18/Aug/2017 21:05:20] "POST /account/password_reset/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection has been dropped by the software on the host computer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\dev_place\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", lin
e 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Mihai\Desktop\dev_place\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", lin
e 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "c:\users\mihai\miniconda3\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 36, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'**

Why am I getting this error only by pressing the ENTER?

Also, I'm not getting the 'success' message in console.

I use:
Django 11.1,
Jquery 3.2.1,
Semantic-Ui 2.2,
jQuery serializeObject 2.5.0 (for serializeForm).
Windows 8.1

EDIT: I set debug to true and I started to look for some errors:
`XHR Aborted (Most likely caused by page navigation or CORS Policy)`

I noticed that `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection has been dropped by the software on the host computer` in the traceback call.

I haven't figured it out yet.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance for answers!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

The problem is that when I press ENTER, .preventDefault() is not called.

A person on github came with:

```
$("#form").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Now it's working just fine, but wow, that huge error only for preventDefault().